# Use a field or override a method to define a value of an abstract class

Tags: java

When setting a value of a parent class, which way is more preferable:

Set a field

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    final Integer damage;
}
public class Knive extends Weapon {
    public Knive(){
        damage = 100;
    }
}
```

Override a method

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    public abstract int getDamage();
}
public class Knive extends Weapon {
    @Override
    public int getDamage(){
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Or is it just personal taste?

Comment: this two ways are completly different, in one you have a variable and can be set, get etc in the second way you have only a method that return you a value. I think in general as the OOP wants you must define the variable damage and create setter and getter method, this is the best way

Comment: for my concerns the value is static, to make it clear i added final

Comment: It totally depends, If you want restricted access and more customization during get/set the use getter/setter things. This will help you in providing more control on it (access and scope)

Comment: In this case where you want a value that will not change you can go with the overridden method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depend on the situation. Both examples correct.

Your fist approach is more preferably when you have inheritance, and the're general logic for number of child classes. **BUT**, do make your property `protected`.

Second approach, is more suitable when you use light classes, like strategies without default implementation. In this case you can change your parent class to `interface`.

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    protected final Integer damage;

    protected Weapon(Integer damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    // more logic here
}

public class Knive extends Weapon {
    public Knive(){
        super(100);
    }
}
```

***OR***

```
public interface Weapon {
    Integer getDamage();
}

public class Knive implements Weapon {
    // light-weight strategy

    public Integer getDamage() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two ways are not opposed. You could use the one, the second or both.
But these don't have the same intention.
A constructor with parameter allows to value the created instance with this parameter : it sets the instance state.

While specifying a method as abstract allows to define a contract that subclasses have to respect.  In this way the base class or any other class can rely on this method to perform some logic. The template method uses this idea.

Suppose you have a class `Warrior` that has a `Weapon` as field, you could compute the damage performed by a  `Weapon` thanks to this method that each subclass will have to implement :

```
public class Warrior{
   private Weapon weapon;
   // ...
   public void attack(Warrior otherWarrior){
        otherWarrior.receiveAttack(weapon.getDamage());
   }
}
```

Now nothing prevents you to store the `damage` information that you received in `Weapon` subclass :

```
public class Knive extends Weapon {
    private int damage; 

    public Knive(int damage){
       this.damage = damage;
    }
    @Override
    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }
}
```

As explained earlier the two approaches are not opposed at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on when and where do you want to set the value, but note that an abstract class can have field, methods and even constructors, it just can't be instantiated. so for the example you provided I prefer using this:

```
abstract class Weapon{
   private int damage;

   public Weapon(int damage) {
       this.damage = damage;
   }

   public int getDamage() {
       return damage;
   }
}

class Knife extends weapon{
   //damage as a parameter
   public Knife(int damage) {
       super(damage);
   }

   //damage as a default value
   public Knife(){
       super(100);
   }
}
```

then you can use it this way:

```
Weapon knife = new Knife(100);
Weapon defaultKnife = new Knife();
System.out.print(knife.getDamage()); --->100
```

You can also have getter and setter methods in the parent class and you don't even have to override anything in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is about personal taste but about the reusability, correctness, and uniformity across extending classes.

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    protected Integer damage;
    public void setDamage(Integer damage){
        this.damage = damage;
    }
    public Integer getDamage(){
        return this.damage;
    }
}
public class Knive extends Weapon {
    public Knive(){
        setdamage(100);//or damage = 100;
    }
}
```

The setter and getter would be the same for all of the extending classes. In case if you want to explicitly override the setter and getter for some specific result, you could override it.